# force placement on top of page

Tags: floats, positioning

I have some tables that get sent to the end of the text but I would like to place them on top of pages within the text. Is there something like `T` that is the equivalent of `H` from `float` for top placement?

Comment: The tables are probably too big to fit on the page within a float. Do you receive any warnings in the `.log`?

Comment: No, there is no warning and the table is a little shorter than half the page. I have a similar table that does fit on top of a page.

Comment: Okay, then we'll need something in the form of code that reproduces the problem in order to see what's going on. Can you provide a minimal example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing?

Comment: I will create one once I have excluded another potential cause.

Comment: it's hard to say given no input but if you use `[!tp]` it will go to the top of a page unless there really is no way to do that in which case it will go on a float page (and you can make float pages top aligned rather than vertically centered)

Comment: This really solved the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you use `[!tp]` it will go to the top of a page unless there really is no way to do that in which case it will go on a float page (and you can make float pages top aligned rather than vertically centered)